# How to fade image src attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I found that it can be done like this:

```
$(".topImage img")
        .mouseover(function() { 
            var src = $(this).attr("src").match(/[^\.]+/) + "-bw.png";
            $(this).fadeOut("fast").attr("src", src).fadeIn("fast");
        })
        .mouseout(function() {
            var src = $(this).attr("src").replace("-bw.png", ".png");                
            $(this).fadeOut("fast").attr("src", src).fadeIn("fast");
        });
    });
```

but this makes it bad because it fades the previous src out completely. Is there a way I could transition that src change so that there is no "now it's a white background before the new src loads in" ?

**Edit**

```
<div class="topImage">
    <img src="<?=$img[0]?>">
</div>
```

This is how it must remain - only one image in the `topImage` container so haveing two images that change opacity, is not an option.

Comment: Why do you want to change the src instead of putting one image on the other ?

Comment: Think you're going about this in the wrong way Xeen, think about it from another perspective. Don't change the src of the image, add another image on top and alter the Alpha values

Comment: you mean image not image src attribute

Comment: You asked for one image I don't think anyone read that requirement... :|

Answer (score 1):

You can even do it without JS at all. There is a lot of way to do it, but here is one : http://codepen.io/mbrillaud/pen/MwwgWZ

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="//lorempicsum.com/futurama/350/200/2" alt="" />
  <img src="//lorempicsum.com/futurama/350/200/1" alt="" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.container img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
.container img:last-child:hover{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't quite use this because of the way my plugin is built (I didn't make it). So apart from this, is there some other way?

Comment: We need to know your constraints then.

Comment: Updated my question with constraint :)

Comment: How to do with one img?

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways to handle this.

Look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/txezfv7d/)

One image is always visible. The second image is simply faded in or out.

This is the only jquery code you need to achieve the effect

```
  /* Set images to full screen */        
    $(".fader").mouseover(function() {
        $("#mask2").stop().fadeIn(800);
    });
    $(".fader").mouseout(function() {
        $("#mask2").stop().fadeOut(800);
    });
```

The rest of the work is done by the css

```
.fader {
    border: 5px solid blue;
    background-color: white;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: fixed;
}
.mask {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -10;
    min-width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-size: cover;
}
#mask1 {
    background-image: url("http://test.coffeeshop.abcde.biz/cascara/img/bg_start.jpg");
}
#mask2 {
    background-image: url("http://test.coffeeshop.abcde.biz/cascara/img/bg_start2.jpg");
    display: none; /* Initial state */
}
```